# hide the price for protected products in shop page WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, password-protection

how to [hide the price for protected products in shop page  WooCommerce ?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VwFkK.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To hide the price for protected products you can add a filter for displaying the price html and check if the product is protected, by checking to see if a password has been set, and if so return no value.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'hide_protected_product_price', 10, 2 );
function hide_protected_product_price( $price, $product ) {
    if ( ! empty( $product->get_post_password() ) && ! is_single() ) {
        return '';
    }
    return $price;
}
```

"Protected:" is added by WordPress not WooCommerce. To replace "Protected:" with "Reserved:" you need to add the protected_title_format filter. To make sure you only do it for products, first check the post_type

```
function jt_replace_product_protected_text( $prepend ) {
    global $post;
    
    if ( $post->post_type == 'product' ) {
        return __( 'Reserved: %s' );
    }
    return $prepend;
}
add_filter( 'protected_title_format', 'jt_replace_product_protected_text' );
```